# How to find the column name of first empty cell in a row?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my sample data.   [image: my data looks like this]

I want to select the first empty cell in row 1, which is column D, and use this columnname to fill data using range function. In simple words, i want to fill data in D2:D3. I wrote a code like this- but this writes data to C2:C3 not D2:D3.

```
    Dim row As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Variant

    lastcolumn = Split(Workbooks("Release.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Cells.Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
lastrow = Workbooks("Release3.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To lastrow

        Range(lastcolumn & row).Value = "success"

    Next
```

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the column letter. If the fourth column is column D, then the column header is blank. So you want to copy the blank cell down? What's the point? Please use a better data sample that makes some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way:-

```
Dim R As Long                       ' "row" is reserved for Excel's use
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Variant

With Workbooks("Release.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4")
    ' observe the leading period in ".Rows.Count"
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    For R = 2 To lastRow

        .Cells(R, lastColumn).Value = "success"

    Next
End With
```

The difference between `lastRow` and `lastColumn` in your setup is that you want to know the last used row but the next free column. [next free] = [last used] + 1. I think your contraption actually works - didn't test - but the above is more main stream.

Comment: i too have no idea where my code went wrong. But your's works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop, just use `Value` property over the whole [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Variant

With Workbooks("Release.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet4")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    .Range(.Cells(2, lastColumn), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Value = "success"
End With
```